# How do I display a switch and picker control inside a Shell Flyout menu in Maui?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I'm creating an internal mobile application for our company.
I'm working with the Shell navigation and my goal is to create a flyout menu with a switch and a picker control. What I would want to have is something like this:

[image]

The "Enable dark mode" item should have a switch attached to it and the "Language" item should be a picker control for selecting languages. Initially I thought about implementing it like so:

```
<ShellContent Title="Enable dark mode">
    <Switch />
</ShellContent>
```

But that does not work. While doing some research I came across the possibility to create a template for menu items and implement the switch control into the template like this:

```
<Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Switch />
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

While that does work, as the switch gets shown when creating a menu item, I can only create one template. So I can create the switch, but not the picker, as I would need another template for that.

I also came across custom DataTemplateSelectors that return a specific `DataTemplate` (so either the template for a switch control or the picker control). I don't know if that would have worked since I was not able to figure out how to implement the custom `DataTemplate`s and the `Selector` into my `AppShell.xaml`.

I'm pretty lost right now. Any help and adivce is greatly appreciated!

Is it possible to create a flyout menu like this while using Shell?  Is it possible at all? Do I need to walk the "old" way, turn my back on Shell and start to use the original navigation and flyout pages from Xamarin?

Comment: `<ShellContent>` represents a Shell navigation item for any page of type `ContentPage` (c.f. [Shell pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages)). You cannot use arbitrary views inside of a `<ShellContent>`. Instead, you would need to [replace Shell's flyout content](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#replace-flyout-content) and implement any layout you want. That then supports any type of content, such as `Switch` and other controls. By doing that, you won't be able to use `MenuItem` and `ShellContent`, though.

Comment: @Julian ok thank you for the input, I will try that. Not using ShellContent means that I need to manually handle page navigation, right? Are there any other disadvantages with not using ShellContent?

Comment: Correct, you'll need to handle Shell navigation yourself. I'm currently working on a similar issue. I also don't see any major downsides of not using ShellContent. It depends on the use case, but since you want a custom flyout, that's the price, I guess and in my case that's more of an advantage as it brings me flexibility.

Comment: Alright, thank you again. Have a good one!